# Situation where visa was not required for a connecting airport but delay or issues with the airlines visa to be now required

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas, abu-dhabi, etihad

I will be travelling to Indianapolis International Airport (IND) from Kolkata International Airport (CCU) and in fact this will be my first solo international flight journey and also the first one where I will have transit points in between the origin and destination of the journey.

My flight has a transit stop at Abu Dhabi International Airport (AUH). Based on what I have heard from the travel helpdesk, it seems that I won't require a visa for Abu Dhabi because my transit time is lesser than 24 hours and because I won't be exiting the airport.

However, I am worried thinking about this situation that if it so happens that my connecting flight from AUH gets delayed or due to some other reason (where I have no role to play) I am required to wait for 24 hours or more at Abu Dhabi, then technically it would now require me to have an Abu Dhabi visa, which I won't have with me. In this situation, what is the standard operating procedure?

Just for information: I would be travelling with a US F1 visa and I hold an Indian citizenship.

Comment: Good question, one thing I would like to see added, your nationality, as it is almost always needed in visa questions.

Comment: If your current transit time is more than 8 hours, you can apply for a free transit visa in advance through Etihaad. If it is less tham 8 hours, then you always have the option for visa on arrival, as mentioned by others, in case of delays. Also, Abu Dhabi has US pre-clearance so you will go through US immigration amd customs in Abu Dhabi and will arrive in the US as a domestic passenger.

Comment: To answer in general: do what crew or airport authorities ask you. You can imagine that "visa free 1 day transit" has always a risk (and independent of the passport holder), so countries has procedures (automatic extension, you may be allowed only to airport and a specific hotel, etc. Note: there are many unforeseen cases (and they happens regularly). You may be forced to land in an other country because of medical emergency, etc.). Do not worry to much (if you have correct documentation for your original planed travel).

Comment: @Willeke I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: In general immigration understands flight delays and doesn't consider a plane taking off late as an overstay.  I do not know anything of Abu Dhabi, though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your case it's rather easy, as you hold a valid US visa. This allows you to apply for a **visa on arrival** valid for 14 days, assuming you're an Indian citizen.

According to the [UAE Embassy in Washington DC](https://www.uae-embassy.org/visas-services/visas-for-non-us-citizens) all the way at the bottom:

> **Indian citizens**
>
> - All Indian citizens holding U.S. visas, green cards, U.K Resident    Permits, or EU resident permits can receive entry visa upon arrival to UAE valid for 14 days for a charge of AED 100.
> - They have the option to extend their stay only once for an additional    14 days for AED250.
> - All documents must be valid for at least six months from the expected    time of arrival to UAE.

Comment: Given that this visa is not free, it would be good to cover (if possible) whether the OP would actually *need* to get it in the situation that he is concerned about.